# Detect if headphones (not microphone) are plugged in to an iOS device

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I need to change my audio depending on whether or not headphones are plugged in. I'm aware of kAudioSessionProperty_AudioInputAvailable, which will tell me if there's a microphone, but I'd like to test for any headphones, not just headphones with a built-in microphone. Is this possible?

Comment: @Brad Larson The answer to that question didn't give me the information I need. My question specifies _headphones_, not microphone. I believe the accepted answer to the question you linked to describes how to detect if a microphone is plugged in.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're asking a refinement of that question where simply detecting the audio input isn't good enough.  Perhaps some of the discussion around [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238758/how-can-i-detect-if-headphones-are-connected-to-an-ipod-touch-g1) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that question.

Comment: Maybe, nearly two years on, you should accept the answer...?

Answer (score 28):

Here is a method of my own which is a slightly modified version of one found on this site : http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9982-play-record-same-time.html

```
- (BOOL)isHeadsetPluggedIn {
    UInt32 routeSize = sizeof (CFStringRef);
    CFStringRef route;

    OSStatus error = AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute,
                                              &routeSize,
                                              &route);

    /* Known values of route:
     * "Headset"
     * "Headphone"
     * "Speaker"
     * "SpeakerAndMicrophone"
     * "HeadphonesAndMicrophone"
     * "HeadsetInOut"
     * "ReceiverAndMicrophone"
     * "Lineout"
     */

    if (!error && (route != NULL)) {

        NSString* routeStr = (NSString*)route;

        NSRange headphoneRange = [routeStr rangeOfString : @"Head"];

        if (headphoneRange.location != NSNotFound) return YES;

    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: this just doesn't seem to work :( care to update your answer?

Comment: what doesn't work? doesn't compile? I use this piece of code in a game and it works for me.

Comment: NO is always returned regardless if my earphones are plugged in

Comment: What is the value of 'error' and 'route' with your earphones plugged?

Comment: Hi I've found that this works with the actual device but not the simulator. There is 0 error, and the route returns "Speaker". Any idea why?

Comment: this is normal, it will only work on the actual device.

Comment: how would I re write the OSStatus error variable for iOS7 audiosessiongetproperty is deprecated..

Comment: I think [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21382748/1693173) is preferable because it uses constants defined by Apple on the port routing.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a solution based on rob mayoff's comment:

```
- (BOOL)isHeadsetPluggedIn
{
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription *route = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute];

    BOOL headphonesLocated = NO;
    for( AVAudioSessionPortDescription *portDescription in route.outputs )
    {
        headphonesLocated |= ( [portDescription.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones] );
    }
    return headphonesLocated;
}
```

Simply link to the AVFoundation framework.

Answer (score 3):

Just a heads up for any future readers of this post.

Most of the AVToolbox methods have been deprecated with the release of iOS 7 without alternative so audio listeners are now largely redundancy

Answer (score 1):

I started with the code given above by jpsetung, but there were a few issues with it for my use case:

- No evidence of something called `kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute` in the docs
- Leaks `route`
- No audio session check
- String check for headphones instead of logical awareness of categories
- I was more interested in whether the iPhone was using its speakers, with "headphones" meaning "anything other than speakers".  I feel that leaving out options like "bluetooth", "airplay", or "lineout" was dangerous.

This implementation broadens the check to allow for any type of specified output:

```
BOOL isAudioRouteAvailable(CFStringRef routeType)
{
    /*
    As of iOS 5:
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_LineOut;
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_Headphones;
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BluetoothHFP;
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BluetoothA2DP;
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInReceiver;
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInSpeaker;
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_USBAudio;
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_HDMI;
    kAudioSessionOutputRoute_AirPlay;
    */

    //Prep
    BOOL foundRoute = NO;
    CFDictionaryRef description = NULL;

    //Session
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    });

    //Property
    UInt32 propertySize;
    AudioSessionGetPropertySize(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteDescription, &propertySize);
    OSStatus error = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteDescription, &propertySize, &description);
    if ( !error && description ) {
        CFArrayRef outputs = CFDictionaryGetValue(description, kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Outputs);
        CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(outputs);
        if ( outputs && count ) {
            for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                CFDictionaryRef route = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(outputs, i);
                CFStringRef type = CFDictionaryGetValue(route, kAudioSession_AudioRouteKey_Type);
                NSLog(@"Got audio route %@", type);

                //Audio route type
                if ( CFStringCompare(type, routeType, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo ) {
                    foundRoute = YES;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if ( error ) {
        NSLog(@"Audio route error %ld", error);
    }

    //Cleanup
    if ( description ) {
        CFRelease(description);
    }

    //Done
    return foundRoute;  
}
```

Used like so:

```
if ( isAudioRouteAvailable(kAudioSessionOutputRoute_BuiltInSpeaker) ) {
    //Do great things...
}
```

Comment: Check out `-[AVAudioSession currentRoute]` for an Objective-C interface to this information as of iOS 6.0.

Comment: Definitely a good note, but only if you are linking to AVFoundation (the code above is for AudioToolbox)