# Context for detecting earphones on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to detect when user unplug his earphones. It seems we can do this by using the audio route related functions as AudioSessionAddPropertyListener.

I have a question though:

- Is it possible to use this both when application is open or running in background?
- If yes, what happens if the user keeps the application running in background for a long time? Will I still be able to detect when user removes his earphones?

Comment: Hope this might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728781/detect-if-headphones-not-microphone-are-plugged-in-to-an-ios-device