# SpeakHere voice recorder fails after AVAudioPlayer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, voice-recording

I am using Apple's SpeakHere example in my project. I can record voice and play without problems..

The problem occurs when I change the view controller where I am using AVAudioPlayer to play recorded voices.. If I go back to SpeakHereViewController to record once again, then it keeps saying "ERROR: metering failed". Why is it happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set a break point and check if error = AudioSessionSetActive(true); is being called inside awakeFromNib whenever you go back.