# Are headphones plugged in? iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, headphones

Developing an app for an iPhone with audio files that need to be listened too through headphones.

How do I check if headphones aren't plugged in so I can tell the user to plug in headphones.

I have the following code from another thread but the audioSessionGetProperty method is deprecated. Anyone know how to alter the following code to make this work OR have there own code/solution.

Thanks.

```
- (BOOL)isHeadsetPluggedIn {
    UInt32 routeSize = sizeof (CFStringRef);
    CFStringRef route;


    //Maybe changing it to something like the following would work for iOS7?
    //AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    //OSStatus error = [session setCategory:kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute...?


    //the line below is whats giving me the warning
    OSStatus error = AudioSessionGetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute,
                                              &routeSize,
                                              &route);

    /* Known values of route:
     * "Headset"
     * "Headphone"
     * "Speaker"
     * "SpeakerAndMicrophone"
     * "HeadphonesAndMicrophone"
     * "HeadsetInOut"
     * "ReceiverAndMicrophone"
     * "Lineout"
     */

    if (!error && (route != NULL)) {

        NSString* routeStr = (__bridge NSString*)route;

        NSRange headphoneRange = [routeStr rangeOfString : @"Head"];

        if (headphoneRange.location != NSNotFound) return YES;

    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: what you mean by full working code?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This should work, but I cannot test it right now, I'll do in the evening.

```
- (BOOL)isHeadsetPluggedIn {
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* route = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute];
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* desc in [route outputs]) {
        if ([[desc portType] isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)

Comment: How do I put this into an action

Answer (score 59):

Just to extend @Antonio's answer. If you need to detect whether the user has pulled out or plugged in the headphone.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

---

```
// [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]; // @Boris edited: you may need it if there is no `AVAudioSession instance` created before. If doesn't work, uncomment this line.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioRouteChangeListenerCallback:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
// don't forget to `removeObserver:`
```

---

```
// If the user pulls out he headphone jack, stop playing.
- (void)audioRouteChangeListenerCallback:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *interuptionDict = notification.userInfo;

    NSInteger routeChangeReason = [[interuptionDict valueForKey:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] integerValue];

    switch (routeChangeReason) {

        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable:
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable");
            NSLog(@"Headphone/Line plugged in");
            break;

        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable:
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable");
            NSLog(@"Headphone/Line was pulled. Stopping player....");
            break;

        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange:
            // called at start - also when other audio wants to play
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I have tested this and works great!

Comment: from docs: If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its dealloc method.

Comment: this didn't work with me in swift until I passed AVAudioSession.sharedInstance() as the parameter `object` for notification center instead of nil, i.e. `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioRouteChangeListenerCallback:)
                                             name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
                                           object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];`

Answer (score 12):

#### Swift 3:

### To check if headphones are connected

```
extension AVAudioSession {

    static var isHeadphonesConnected: Bool {
        return sharedInstance().isHeadphonesConnected
    }

    var isHeadphonesConnected: Bool {
        return !currentRoute.outputs.filter { $0.isHeadphones }.isEmpty
    }

}

extension AVAudioSessionPortDescription {
    var isHeadphones: Bool {
        return portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones
    }
}
```

Then you can just `print("isHeadphones connected: \(AVAudioSession.isHeadphonesConnected)")`

### Listening to Changes

In **Swift 3** the syntax is this:

```
func handleRouteChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
    let reasonRaw = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? NSNumber,
    let reason = AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason(rawValue: reasonRaw.uintValue)
    else { fatalError("Strange... could not get routeChange") }
    switch reason {
    case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
        print("oldDeviceUnavailable")
    case .newDeviceAvailable:
        print("newDeviceAvailable") 
        if AVAudioSession.isHeadphonesConnected {
             print("Just connected headphones")
        } 
    case .routeConfigurationChange:
        print("routeConfigurationChange")
    case .categoryChange:
        print("categoryChange")
    default:
        print("not handling reason")
    }
}

func listenForNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleRouteChange(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: nil)
}
```

Notice use of:

```
 if AVAudioSession.isHeadphonesConnected {
    print("Just connected headphones")
 }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It does not answer if headphones are plugged in or not.

Comment: @Jonny I edited my answer to include check of headphones. Please upvote my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Does this work? There is no member `isHeadphonesConnected` in `AVAudioSession` in Swift 3 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession

Comment: @thuanle, look carefully at the code, `isHeadphonesConnected` used in the extension.

Answer (score 4):

@Warif's code in **Swift 2.0** with little changes ...

```
func audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (notif: NSNotification){
        let userInfo:[NSObject:AnyObject] = notif.userInfo!
        println("\(userInfo)")
        let routChangeReason = UInt((userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey]?.integerValue)!)
        switch routChangeReason {
        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable.rawValue:
            self.println("Headphone/Line plugged in");
            break;

        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.OldDeviceUnavailable.rawValue:
            //If the headphones was pulled move to speaker
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)
            } catch _ {
            }
            self.println("Headphone/Line was pulled. Stopping player....");
            break;

        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.CategoryChange.rawValue:
            // called at start - also when other audio wants to play
            self.println("AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

:D

Answer (score 3):

In Swift (as of 1.2):

```
    func headsetPluggedIn() -> Bool {
    let route = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    return (route.outputs as! [AVAudioSessionPortDescription]).filter({ $0.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones }).count > 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3.0 version

- Method to check if headphones are plugged or any Bluetooth device with audio output connected

```
    func bluetoothOrHeadphonesConnected() -> Bool {

        let outputs = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs

        for output in outputs{

            if output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP ||
               output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP ||
               output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothLE ||
               output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones {
                return true
            }

        }

        return false 
    }
```

- It's important to check if the headphones are plugged out while you listen any audio.

```
 
    private func setupObservers() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.audioRouteChangeListener), name: .AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: nil)

    }

    func audioRouteChangeListener(notification: Notification) {

        guard let audioRouteChangeReason = notification.userInfo![AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? Int else { return }

        switch audioRouteChangeReason {

            case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.oldDeviceUnavailable.hashValue:
                //plugged out

            default:
                break

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please don't post [identical answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44026342) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @PaulRoub

Comment: The question asserts that the app needs to be used with headphones, in particular.  The Bluetooth ports you listed can also apply to cars, portable speakers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(plugout:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];
-(void)plugout:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    isRemovedHeadset = YES;
}
```

and handle your code using this isRemovedHeadset boolean in your

```
if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) 
{
    if(isRemovedHeadset)
    {
        isRemovedHeadset = NO;
        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [moviePlayer play];
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sajjon solution on Swift 5 with RxSwift

```
func handleRouteChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
        let reasonRaw = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? NSNumber,
        let reason = AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason(rawValue: reasonRaw.uintValue)
        else { fatalError("Strange... could not get routeChange") }
    switch reason {
    case .oldDeviceUnavailable:
        print("oldDeviceUnavailable")
    case .newDeviceAvailable:
        print("newDeviceAvailable")
        if AVAudioSession.isHeadphonesConnected {
            print("Just connected headphones")
        }
    case .routeConfigurationChange:
        print("routeConfigurationChange")
    case .categoryChange:
        print("categoryChange")
    default:
        print("not handling reason")
    }
}

func listenForNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.rx
        .notification(AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification)
        .subscribe(onNext: { (n) in
            self.handleRouteChange(n)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```