# Detecting inputs and outputs after app moves to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm trying to detect when `headphones` are plugged into the iPhone. I do this buy the following approach.

```
//Init the AVAudioSession
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];    
    NSError *activationError = nil;

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
}

//Get the current audio session route
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription  *route = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute];
}
```

This works fine and the `route.inputs` and `route.outputs` will contain the `headphones` and the `microphone` for a wired iPhone `headset` and will show the built in receiver and built in microphone when the headphones are unplugged. The problem I'm running into is when I press the home button on my app and it moves to the background. When I bring the app back into the foreground the route.inputs is always empty. My question is: Do I need to set the `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error: &activiationError]` in my appDelegate when `applicaionWillResign` active is called? Because when route.inputs comes back empty, the headphones are still plugged in and should be detected. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**I think a better approach is this :**

```
- (BOOL)isHeadsetPluggedIn 
{
    AVAudioSessionRouteDescription* route = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute];
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* desc in [route outputs]) 
    {
        if ([[desc portType] isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I just tested this and this works even when coming back to foreground from background, and also on viewDiDLoad

**Link to Original [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292586/are-headphones-plugged-in-ios7)**