# How to check for connected bluetooth devices

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, voip, headset

I am developing voip application and currently working on bluetooth support.
Is there a way to check if some bluetooth headset is currently  connected to iOS device?

Comment: look at this post, you might find your solution

Comment: Which post? I don't see any link. :)

Comment: sorry ^_^ this is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728781/detect-if-headphones-not-microphone-are-plugged-in-to-an-ios-device